# Entity Framework TPT Inheritance Move Data Between Tables

Tags: asp.net-mvc, entity-framework, table-per-type

I am looking at using TPT Inheritance with EF. I have the following tables.

StockLocation
StockLocationType

StockLocationType contains the following types:

Bulk
Pickable
Secure

I was thinking of using StockLocation as the base table and create a bulk, pickable and secure table.
In the secure table there will be a column called locked which will make the location locked so no one can pick from it.

To switch a location from pickable to secure, will I have to remove the data from the pickable table and insert it into the secure table and set the locked column to true when the location is locked? and then move it back from the secure table to the pickable table once the location is unlocked?

Or do I have a duplicate record in each table?

It just seems like i'm continuously passing data between the two tables.

Any advice/suggestions would be great.

Answer (score 0):

> To switch a location from pickable to secure, will I have to remove
>   the data from the pickable table and insert it into the secure table
>   and set the locked column to true when the location is locked?

That is not a use case for inheritance. A type of entity is permanent. You cannot change a type of entity in EF (you can do that by executing SQL directly in database but that is hacking EF and it can have unexpected consequences).

> Or do I have a duplicate record in each table?

That is also hardly achievable because you can have record only in single table for derived types otherwise EF will not be able to understand what type is it and fire error.

> It just seems like i'm continously passing data between the two tables.

If your database is designed this way you will have to pass data and you will have to use normal navigation properties for that in EF.